# How to implement image animation via an invisible UIslider?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uislider

I got a question is using UISlider to control a image animation

And this image has invisible slider to cover on it ...

It looks like this
[image]

My question is ... how to adjust image angle ,when I change my slide value ???

So that's I can let the image animation from left pic to right pic ???

Thanks

Webber

upload the sample code [Here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/cwyymn)

Hope someone can help me to figure out this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to rotate the image? Then use:

```
imageView.transform =  GAffineTransformRotate(imageView.transform,RADIANS(degreesToRotate));
```

Comment: This is very close to the answer I want ,But how to set the slider min/max value ,and set up the "degreesToRotate"???
This is my IBAction:int progressAsInt =(int)(invisibleSlider.value + 0.5f);
 if (progressAsInt==0) {
  [dimmerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider0.png"]];
 }
 else {
  [dimmerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider99.png"]];
  dimmerImg.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(dimmerImg.transform, progressAsInt);
 }

Comment: The UISlider value is a float between 0 and 1. So to get the degrees, just multiply 360 with the slider value.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)changeSliderValue:(id)sender{
    int progressAsInt =(int)(invisibleSlider.value);
    if (progressAsInt==0) {
        [dimmerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider0.png"]];
    }
    else {
        [dimmerImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider99.png"]];
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        dimmerImg.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, progressAsInt * M_PI / 180);
        //dimmerImg.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(dimmerImg.transform, progressAsInt);
    }
}
```

This works fine ~